# Getting compilation error after importing AngularFireDatabase and AngularFireList modules from @angular/fire/compat/database library

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am working on an Angular App which requires Firebase integration and I made the following import for one the app services:
`import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';`

However on compilation I am getting this lengthy error message, after which compilation fails:

```
./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:636:28-39 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:642:29-40 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:3052:6-17 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:4208:19-31 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:12857:7-18 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13093:9-20 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13761:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13821:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13835:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13837:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13900:23-29 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13901:19-31 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15481:27-33 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15482:13-25 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15608:16-29 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION$1') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15610:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15621:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15623:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
```

I guess it has something to do with the imports I made or with the compatibility of the `@angular/fire` library version I have installed with my Angular version. Still I can't figure out how I should resolve it.

My Angular version is 14.2.12 and my `@angular/fire` library version is 7.6.1.

Moreover my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AssetRequestFormComponent } from './asset-request-form/asset-request-form.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import { ViewRequestsComponent } from './view-requests/view-requests.component';
import { ConfirmRequestComponent } from './confirm-request/confirm-request.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AssetRequestFormComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    ViewRequestsComponent,
    ConfirmRequestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How should I resolve this issue? am I using outdated libraries? If yes then is there any workaround I can use?

Also for reference, I was following the steps from [this website](https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-14-firebase-crud/)